# How to rename labels in list?

Tags: python

I have a file like that

```
301 my name is joe
303 whatsup
306 how are you doing today
308 what happened?
308 going home
309 let's go
```

I want to convert the labels `301, 303, 306, 308, 308, 309` to `1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5`

How can I rename these labels in order in such a way that similar ones get the same number?

Comment: Please clarify: Is it a typo that the last label in the line below the code is `301` again, while it is `309` in the code? I.e., when a label with the same number as a label a few lines back (but not the last label) is repeated, should it get a new number or the old number again?

Comment: @tobias_k: Yes, it was a typo. My bad. But this makes me curious suppose these labels aren't in order. Then if I have marked 301 as 1 earlier and I come across 301 again, how can I make sure that it should be labeled 1 again?

Comment: The dictionary-based solutions will do just that (that's why I asked), the last-index-based will not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a dictionary to store the mapping from original to new label, and use the current `len` of the dictionary for values that have not yet been mapped, using `setdefault`.

```
>>> labels = 301, 303, 306, 308, 308, 309
>>> names = {}
>>> for l in labels:
...     names.setdefault(l, len(names)+1)
...
>>> names
{301: 1, 303: 2, 306: 3, 308: 4, 309: 5}
```

More complete example:

```
text = """301 my name is joe
303 whatsup
306 how are you doing today
308 what happened?
308 going home
309 let's go""".splitlines()

import re
names = {}
replacer = lambda x: str(names.setdefault(x.group(), len(names) + 1))
for line in text:
    replaced = re.sub(r'^\d+', replacer, line)
    print(replaced)
```

Output:

```
1 my name is joe
2 whatsup
3 how are you doing today
4 what happened?
4 going home
5 let's go
```

Comment: I suspect the OP doesn't know the exact values in advance.  The idea is to number the lines, but give lines with the same label the same number.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Yes, so? Obviously you can do the same in a loop, adding new labels to the dict as they come. Just wanted to provide the minimal code.

Comment: Yes, the solution would be better expressed if it separated the mechanics of simulating the input, from the actual replacer function which would be
eg replacer(input_row, number_map_dict, output_list)

Comment: @MikeW Not sure what you mean. The `replacer` function has to take a regex-match as input and nothing else, but of course you could wrap the entire line-number-replacing-code into another function...

Answer (score 2):

You could use an index which only increments when the label is different from the last one:

```
data = ["301 my name is joe", "303 whatsup", "306 how are you doing today", "308 what happened?", "308 going home", "309 let's go"]

idx = 0
last_index = ""
for i in range(len(data)):
    if last_index != data[i].split(" ")[0]: idx += 1
    print str(idx) + " " + ' '.join(data[i].split(" ")[1:])
    last_index = data[i].split(" ")[0]
```

Result:

```
1 my name is joe
2 whatsup
3 how are you doing today
4 what happened?
4 going home
5 let's go
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `dict` to collect the prefixes and a counter.

```
data = """301 my name is joe
303 whatsup
306 how are you doing today
308 what happened?
308 going home
309 let's go"""

prefixes = {}
i = 1 

for line in data.split("\n"):
    prefix, rest = line.split(" ", 1)
    pr = int(prefix)
    if not pr in prefixes:
        prefixes[pr] = i
        i = i + 1
    newPrefix = prefixes[pr]
    print("{} {}".format(newPrefix, rest))
```

Output:

```
1 my name is joe
2 whatsup
3 how are you doing today
4 what happened?
4 going home
5 let's go
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def update_text(data):
    labels = sorted(set([line.split()[0] for line in data.splitlines()]))
    for inx, line in enumerate(data.splitlines()):
        yield str(labels.index(line.split()[0]) + 1) + ' ' + ' '.join(line.split()[1:])

data = '''301 my name is joe
303 whatsup
306 how are you doing today
308 what happened?
308 going home
309 let's go'''

print '\n'.join(update_text(data))
```

**Output:**

```
1 my name is joe
2 whatsup
3 how are you doing today
4 what happened?
4 going home
5 let's go
```

**Another simple solution:**

```
>>> keys = sorted(set([line.split()[0] for line in data.splitlines()]))
>>> for k, v in enumerate(keys):
...     data = data.replace(v, str(k + 1))
... 
>>> print data
1 my name is joe
2 whatsup
3 how are you doing today
4 what happened?
4 going home
5 let's go
```